# java multi client socket server echoing all clients

Tags: java, sockets

I was working on multi-client sockets and its working just fine, however it came to my mind on how to make the communication public by making the entered string being streamed to all clients.

e.g if there are lets say 3 clients A,B and C and client A sends "foo" to server, I want the server to stream "foo" to clients B and C as well.

The Server Module :

```
package multiclient;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Server {

public static void main(String args[]) {

    Socket s = null;
    ServerSocket ss2 = null;
    System.out.println("Server Listening......");
    try {
        ss2 = new ServerSocket(4445); // can also use static final PORT_NUM , when defined

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Server error");

    }

    while (true) {
        try {
            s = ss2.accept();
            System.out.println("connection Established");
            ServerThread st = new ServerThread(s);
            st.start();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Connection Error");

        }
    }

  }

            }

class ServerThread extends Thread {

String line = null;
BufferedReader is = null;
PrintWriter os = null;
Socket s = null;

public ServerThread(Socket s) {
    this.s = s;
}

public void run() {
    try {
        is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
        os = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("IO error in server thread");
    }

    try {
        line = is.readLine();
        while (line.compareTo("QUIT") != 0) {

            os.println(line);
            os.flush();
            System.out.println("Response to Client  :  " + line);
            line = is.readLine();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {

        line = this.getName(); //reused String line for getting thread name
        System.out.println("IO Error/ Client " + line + " terminated abruptly");
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        line = this.getName(); //reused String line for getting thread name
        System.out.println("Client " + line + " Closed");
    } finally {
        try {
            System.out.println("Connection Closing..");
            if (is != null) {
                is.close();
                System.out.println(" Socket Input Stream Closed");
            }

            if (os != null) {
                os.close();
                System.out.println("Socket Out Closed");
            }
            if (s != null) {
                s.close();
                System.out.println("Socket Closed");
            }

        } catch (IOException ie) {
            System.out.println("Socket Close Error");
        }
    }//end finally
}
```

}

The Client Module:

```
package multiclient;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Client {

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{


InetAddress address=InetAddress.getLocalHost();
Socket s1=null;
String line=null;
BufferedReader br=null;
BufferedReader is=null;
PrintWriter os=null;

try {
    s1=new Socket(address, 4445); // You can use static final constant PORT_NUM
    br= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    is=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s1.getInputStream()));
    os= new PrintWriter(s1.getOutputStream());
}
catch (IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.err.print("IO Exception");
}

System.out.println("Client Address : "+address);
System.out.println("Enter Data to echo Server ( Enter QUIT to end):");

String response=null;
try{
    line=br.readLine(); 
    while(line.compareTo("QUIT")!=0){
            os.println(line);
            os.flush();
            response=is.readLine();
            System.out.println("Server Response : "+response);
            line=br.readLine();

        }



}
catch(IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
System.out.println("Socket read Error");
}
finally{

    is.close();os.close();br.close();s1.close();
            System.out.println("Connection Closed");

}

        }
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

The server can keep a collection of all client sockets (until one is closed). When a client message arrives, server writes it to all client sockets.

There's a problem though, socket.write() is blocking, so if we do it in a loop, a slow client will block the rest of the clients. You can spawn a new thread to write to each individual socket, if there aren't too many clients.

In the blocking IO world, to implement a true full-duplex protocol, it is necessary for server to have two threads per client, one for read, one for write.

You may also try NIO if you are brave enough...

Answer (score 0):

There are many examples. Search for chat server. One good one if you don't mind using a framework is [Netty](http://netty.io/4.0/xref/io/netty/example/securechat/package-summary.html), check the SecureChat example for working code. It is a short and focused example.

Edit: the link takes you to the example code.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest:
1. Keep the threads you create in an ArrayList
2. Create a method in Server called writeString and a lock

```
  private final Lock mutex = new ReentrantLock(true);
  private ArrayList<ServerThread> list = new ArrayList<ServerThread>();
  public void writeString(ServerThread t,String s)
  {
    mutex.lock();

   for(ServerThread th:list)
       if(th!=null && th!=t) //different from the thread receiving the string
          th.writeString(s);  //send string to other threads

    mutex.unlock();
  }
```

3. in ServerThread class, implement writeString method and add a Lock

```
  private final Lock mutex = new ReentrantLock(true);
  public void writeString(String s)
  {
     mutex.lock();
       os.println(s);
       os.flush();
    mutex.unlock();
   }
```

4. Keep a reference to the main Server thread by modifying the constructor

```
  //in ServerThread
  private Server parent=null;
  SeverThread(Socket s, Server parent)
  {
      this.parent=parent;
      /*the rest of the code*/
  }

  //in Server
  ServerThread st = new ServerThread(s,this);
  st.start();
  list.add(st);
```

4. When you read the string in ServerThread, call the Server writeString method in order to notify all the clients

   ```
    parent.writeString(this,s); //calls the method we created at 2.
   ```